# why 3d plot‘s ticks in x,y,z has different directions

Tags: plotting, ticks

```
Plot3D[0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Boxed -> {Left, Bottom, Back},BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.7},TicksStyle -> Black, AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, ViewPoint -> 10 {1.5, -1.5, 1}]
```

It's output is
[image]

Why the ticks on the x-axis are upright, and the y-axis and z-axis are all attached to the plane. How can I make the x axis lie flat. I looked at all the options through AbsoluteOptions, but it does not seem to find any one option to control it.

Comment: With v12.1 on my Mac the ticks are as you show; however, with v12.1.1 both the x and y ticks are up rather than in the plane. I do not know up any method of controlling this short of explicitly drawing them with primitives.

Comment: They’re all technically lying on the plane. Notice how each lie upon a different plane.